# Подскажите как прописать нужное условие при выводе блока php

Tags: php, drupal

Здравствуйте, вывожу программно блок в node.tpl.php cms Drupal 7 :

```
if($node->type=="uslugi" or $node->nid==1021 or $node->nid==169 or $node->nid==168) {
     $block_u = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 89);
    print '<div class="node-type-uslugi">'.$block_u['content'].'</div>';
  }
```

Как дописать в условии не отображать данный блок на страницах node/1597 и node/1598 которые так же относятся к типу материала "uslugi"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо так

```
if($node->type=="uslugi" && ! in_array($node->nid, array(1597, 1598)) || in_array($node->nid, array(1021, 169, 168))) {
    $block_u = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 89);
    print '<div class="node-type-uslugi">'.$block_u['content'].'</div>';
}
```

Теперь условие читается так:

```
Если тип равен "uslugi" и номер не равен 1597 или 1598
     или номер равен 1021 или 169 или 168
то выполнить ...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, все прекрасно работает, очень помогли.